# Python Snowflake Connector - cannot use set statement?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, session-variables, snowflake-connector

I get an error trying to use the set statement to create session variables while using python snowflake connector.

Is this even possible? Or would we have to create our own string interpolation?

Comment: Hi can  you please give us more information what you are trying to do ,  please check this link where they are doing ALTER SESSION SET https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#setting-session-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use *set* statements with the Snowflake Connector if you use the *executemany* Python command and the *EXECUTE IMMEDIATE* Snowflake command.

An example on setting two variables then adding them together would look like:

```
    queries = [
        ['SET a = 2'],
        ['SET b = 3'],
        ['SELECT %a + %b']
    ]
    
    sql = 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE %s'
    
    cursor.executemany(sql, queries)
    print(cursor.fetchall())

    #Returns [(5,)]
```

In this example '%s' is replaced by each of the three strings in 'queries', then those three queries are queued and submitted in one transaction.

If you would like to know more about using 'set' in Python-sent SQL queries, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, and the Python command *executemany*, follow these links:

http://dot-pi.com/use-set-in-sql-commands-sent-from-python/

http://dot-pi.com/use-pythons-executemany-command-to-run-multiple-sql-queries-at-once/

*Note: these are web pages I have written*

Comment: that just seems like a horrible solution in general..to have to break up every one of these commands in a list.